# Populating a popup menu with directory files

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, popupmenu

I'm trying to populate a popup menu from a GUI I made up with GUIDE. I'm doing as follows:

```
TestFiles = dir([pwd '/test/*.txt']);
TestList = [];

for i = 1:length(TestFiles)
    filename = TestFiles(i).name;
    TestList = [TestList filename];
end

set(handles.popup_test,'string',TestList);
```

I'm doing this inside the `popup_test_CreateFcn` method (I'm not really sure that is the right place though).

When trying to launch the GUI I keep getting this:

```
??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in ==> init>popup_test_CreateFcn at 101
set(handles.popup_test,'string',TestList);

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> init at 19
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==> @(hObject,eventdata)init('popup_test_CreateFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


??? Error using ==> struct2handle
Error while evaluating uicontrol CreateFcn
```

So for some reason the `set()` method is not allowing me to populate the popup menu with TestList.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you run your program, the first functions called are the `"create functions"`

So when you do `set(handles.popup_test,'string',TestList);` inside `popup_test_CreateFcn`, the function doesn't know what is `handles` because it is known only after the `"opening function"`. (If you try to print it inside the `"create functions"` it will be empty).

You can do inside this function something like this:

```
handles.popup_test=hObject;  %pass handles the popup menu object
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

And in the opening function `XXXX_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)` you can add:

```
%...define TestList and other things you need
set(handles.popup_test,'string',TestList);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got rid of the errors by now at least. The thing is the popup menu is empty when I run it now. I have the feeling it has to do with where iteration to fill the TestList is placed, did I do right moving that to `XXXX_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)`?

Comment: Try to `set(handles.popup_test,'string',['a';'b';'c']);` and if it worked, hence if you can see `a b c` in your `popup menu`, then you know that the problem with your file.

Comment: Plus you can print the content of your file to see weather it contains the desired values.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you again. Any idea on why populating the popup menu like that I get `??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.` When `str = get(handles.popup_entrenament, 'String');
val = get(handles.popup_entrenament, 'Value');

file = str{val};` to retrieve selected item?

Comment: Nevermind again, I just had to use `mat2cell` so I could actually access a cell instead of a matrix :D